# getElementByID working but jQuery's selector is not

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is driving me insane.  I am trying to select a DOM element by ID in jQuery and remove it.  Despite my best efforts, jQuery keeps giving me                                                          Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #li-/media/photos/KObtu.jpg

But this id definitely does exist in my DOM. So I decided to cut jQuery out of the picture and use plain ol' javascript. This worked beautifully, but I have no idea why.

```
function DeletePhoto() {
    //Remove a photo from the server when the delete button is clicked
    $("#personal-photo-list .delete").click( function() {
        var photoId = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
        $.post("profile/DeletePhoto/", { "photo": photoId }, function(jsonObject){
            $("#li-" + photoId).remove(); //What I actually want to call. Does not work
            $("#li-/media/photos/KObtu.jpg").remove(); //I thought maybe using a variable was throwing things off.  This does not work either
            document.getElementById("li-/media/photos/KObtu.jpg").innerHTML="dsfsdfsdfsdf"; //The exact same id as the statements above. This command successfully replaces the text in the <li> tag
    });
});
```

}

In case anyone is curious, here is a snippet of the HTML:

```
<li id="li-/media/photos/KObtu.jpg">
                <img src="/media/photos/KObtu.jpg"> 
                <p> Uploaded on Sept. 23, 2012 | <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="a-/media/photos/KObtu.jpg" class="delete"> Delete </a> </p>
</li>
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: did you try escaping the '/'?

Comment: @user1556487: As a side-note, `ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").` quote from here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id Just beware the `.` as jQuery treats that as a special case.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl HTML5 doesn't restrict that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as `` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ `` ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: `\\`.

`/` is a meta-character, so you have to escape it.

Comment: Lets just hope the `jpg` won't become a `png` some day or we might be ending up with confusing class names. I forgot what the term for this is when one names classes like `red` and the likes.

Answer (score 2):

Your LI id uses a hyphen (dash), but your jquery selector uses underscore

edit: alternatively, you could use something like:

```
$(this).parents("li").remove();
```

Comment: oops. Originally, my ids had underscores in them, and I switched to a desh because I read somewhere that underscores might fail in id strings.  Unfortunately, I am still having the issue when I use a dash in the jQuery selector.  Let me try the other suggestion you posted.

Comment: presuming the second suggestion works (which it should do :p) I'd suggest getting rid of the IDs on the LI and the A tags - they're no longer needed, and as some of the other posters have pointed out, they're not exactly valid

Answer (score 0):

Try using $("[id='personal-photo-list'] .delete") or $("[id='li-/media/photos/KObtu.jpg']") .
Working jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/42Vyq/1/

jQuery API:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

I had the some problem when a genius developer used the class name 'user.email'